# error message when calculating descriptive statistics

Tags: r

I want to calculate the M, SD, Min, and Max for a given variable in my data. Sample data is:

```
id-visit  x
1-01      5
1-01      1
1-01      6
1-04      NA
1-04      NA
1-04      1
```

Sample code is:

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(id-visit) %>%
  mutate(x_M = mean(x, na.rm = T), x_MIN = min(x, na.rm = T), 
         x_MAX = max(x, na.rm = T), x_SD = sd(x, na.rm = T))
```

When I use this code, I am getting the following error message. I believe this is occurring because I am asking R to return a mean for person 1-04, but they have only 1 value and the rest are missing.

Is there a way I can tell R to assign that person a mean of 1, max of 1, min of 1, and SD of 0?

```
Warning messages:
1: Problem with `mutate()` input `x_MIN`.
ℹ no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
ℹ Input `x_MIN` is `min(x, na.rm = T)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 499: subject_id = "1-04". 
2: In min(x, na.rm = T) :
  no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: Problem with `mutate()` input `x_MAX`.
ℹ no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
ℹ Input `x_MAX` is `max(x, na.rm = T)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 499: subject_id = "1-04". 
4: In max(x, na.rm = T) :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are warning messages. You can `replace` NA's with 1/0 based on the column name.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id.visit) %>%
  mutate(x_M = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), x_MIN = min(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
         x_MAX = max(x, na.rm = TRUE), x_SD = sd(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
         across(x_M:x_MAX, tidyr::replace_na, 1), 
         x_SD = replace(x_SD ,is.na(x_SD), 0))

#  id.visit     x   x_M x_MIN x_MAX  x_SD
#  <chr>    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 1-01         5     4     1     6  2.65
#2 1-01         1     4     1     6  2.65
#3 1-01         6     4     1     6  2.65
#4 1-04        NA     1     1     1  0   
#5 1-04        NA     1     1     1  0   
#6 1-04         1     1     1     1  0
```

Comment: Thank you @Ronak Shah. Much appreciated!